# Fastest SSL cipher implementation for Nginx if strength is NOT needed?

Tags: nginx, ssl, performance

I have a use case that is the inverse of most: I'd like to implement very weak SSL ciphers in the name of performance, with the option to fall back to stronger ciphers if the client requests it.

Backstory: I have a public-facing web server that receives a giant quantity of POST traffic from thousands of remote clients, with each POST being rather small. A client will a payload once and disconnect. The server takes on thousands of these connections per minute, so the overhead of SSL negotiation adds up.

The data in question does NOT need to be secure; the reason for using HTTPS at all is because the traffic originates from a JavaScript tag on a given website, and if said site is using HTTPS, then our supplementary traffic must use HTTPS as well to prevent warning about mixing secure and insecure content. Again, the security of the data in this connection is not important at all, even if the "parent" site is SSL secured for whatever reason.

Because of this, it makes sense to me to present the weakest possible cipher to clients while maintaining full compatibility with browsers. I'd also like to offer the option to increase security to full ECDHE if requested, merely to satisfy more security-conscious clients, but definitely as a secondary option.

A few years ago, some variant of RC4 would have fit the bill, but since that is universally panned as insecure today, I'm concerned that browser compatibility may become an issue. In the wake of that - what ciphers would offer me the features I'm looking for above, with the greatest speed?

Comment: aes128 with intel aesni hardware acceleration is probably the fastest. It is conveniently also very secure.

Comment: Great call on utilizing AES-NI, I will test that out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The data in question does NOT need to be secure... prevent warning about mixing secure

I think you should probably understand the reason for these warnings instead of just trying to ignore them as best as possible. If content on a secure site is included from a insecure site it might affect the security of the original site.

> The server takes on thousands of these connections per minute, so the overhead of SSL negotiation adds up.

A fast cipher will usually not reduce the overhead of the SSL negotiation significantly. The ciphers gets mainly used **after** the negotiation is done and has only a small performance impact. Some part of the cipher is relevant for the handshake (the key exchange) but unless you choose a very slow key exchange (see below) the main performance impact comes from the multiple round-trips inside needed for the negotiation. These can only be reduced if you support the reuse of sessions, so that a full handshake is only needed  for the first request and the next time the same client connects a less expensive session resume can be done. HTTP keep-alive can help a lot too. Of course both these optimization work only if you actually have multiple requests from the same client.

There are some ciphers with very slow key exchange, which you probably don't want to use in your case. All DHE-* ciphers have a large performance impact, but have the advantage of providing forward secrecy. You get the same advantage with ECDHE ciphers without having too much of a performance impact on today's hardware, but an overhead is still there. Using ciphers like `AES128-GCM-SHA256` should be a good choice both in terms of performance and in terms of security.

At the end the choice of cipher depends also on the clients you use. While `RC4-SHA` is fast it is considered insecure and more and more clients disable it. Thus you might and with a fast server nobody can use because browsers disabled insecure ciphers.

Comment: Actually, reviewing my use case, I don't think the "content mixing" warning is even an issue here; the communication is unidirectional (client -> server), and it's not including any off-site content into the page that is rendered for the client.  So the main concern would simply be broad browser support.

Given that RC4-SHA is being disabled by clients, it sounds like from what you and @Andrew Domaszek have said, a flavor of AES128 is the optimal solution here.

Answer (score 2):

The absolute fastest would be eNull. To include `eNull` in `ssl_ciphers`, try `aNULL:eNULL:MD5:LOW:HIGH` for your cipher string. Typically, however you are going to negotiate the highest supported cipher. You therefore may want to cap it by using `!HIGH`, but be sure to thoroughly test this. You will at least need to keep in LOW as I believe most browsers would refuse to use the null and md5 ciphers at all.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your urgency you could wait for adoption of ["Salsa20"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20) and ["ChaCha"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20#ChaCha_variant) in particular that is intended to be direct replacement for RC4 in terms of performance. However, right now only google Chrome and latest releases of Android OS support it on the client side and it is not in OpenSSL yet, so no servers support yet. Otherwise I agree with others on AES-IN.

Answer (score 0):

https://discussions.qualys.com/thread/16005 lists some benchmarks of both bulk cipher operations and key exchange.  For bulk ciphers, aes128-ccm seems to be the fastest, and for key exchange, ecdhe (with nist p256) is quite a bit faster than 2048 bit dhe, but rsa key exchange is slightly faster.  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5551094/ lists a comparison of key exchange methods shows that Curve25519 (aka X25519) key exchange is significantly faster than nist p256)

Putting that all together, with a modern processor and ssl library, your best best is probably TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM (the GCM suites are almost as fast and more widely used) with X25519 for key exchange.  In the interest of client compatibility, you could also offer TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, which uses RSA key exchange.  You could also offer the RC4 suites, but browsers may start rejecting that algorithm.   It ultimately depends on your server's hardware, so it is probably a good idea to try benchmarking several cipher suites and see how many connections per second you can do.